# how do i fix this resizing issue with my container and div boxes

Tags: html, css, image, responsive

*If there is another thread with this answer that would be great as a disclaimer*

Please refer to the video on what my issue is. I want the div and header to resize proportionally when I make it bigger and smaller. The issue is that as I am resizing the div and header unalign from each other and look weird.

Is the only solution a media query?

here is a imgur video link to see the issue.

Here is the code that I have so far.

**The container box is orange only for navigational purposes while building the design. The box will not have color by the end.**

```css
html {
   background-color:#0000ff;
  }
  #container {
   background-color:orange;
   width:100%;
  }
  #title {
   text-align:center;
   color:#ffffff;
   box-shadow: #ffffff 0px 0px 10px 10px;
   margin:75px auto;
   width:75%;
   padding:20px 10px 20px 10px;
   border-radius: 5px;
   letter-spacing: 15px;
   font-size:25px;
   line-height: 30px;
  }

  #image {
   width:50%;
   box-shadow:#ff0000 0px 0px 10px 10px;
   margin-left:165px;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>mockup week three</title>
</head>
<body>
 <div id="container">
 <div id="title">
  Week three
 </div>
 <div id="gif">
<image id="image" src="https://media.giphy.com/media/l41m4rC9j8kMjXB0k/source.gif" width="100%"></image>
 </div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this - I have done few CSS edits.

```css
html {
   background-color:#0000ff;
  }
  #container {
   background-color:orange;
   width:100%;
  }
  #title {
   text-align:center;
   color:#ffffff;
   box-shadow: #ffffff 0px 0px 10px 10px;
   margin:75px auto;
   width:75%;
   padding:20px 10px 20px 10px;
   border-radius: 5px;
   letter-spacing: 15px;
   font-size:25px;
   line-height: 30px;
  }

    #gif {
   text-align:center;
   margin:75px auto;
   width:75%;
  }

  #image {
   width:100%;
   box-shadow:#ff0000 0px 0px 10px 10px;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>mockup week three</title>
</head>
<body>
 <div id="container">
 <div id="title">
  Week three
 </div>
 <div id="gif">
<image id="image" src="https://media.giphy.com/media/l41m4rC9j8kMjXB0k/source.gif" width="100%"></image>
 </div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```